# Add or remove borders from all tables in a document

Tags: tables, border

I have a LaTeX document with several tables. All these tables do not have borders. I would like to add borders to all these tables. Adding borders one by one to each table is a daunting task. Is there a simpler way to add (and remove) borders to all the tables in a LaTeX document?

Comment: why you should add borders? tables without border are more beautiful :-). i'm afraid, that this change you should do manually, maybe with help of editor (difficult to say since i don't know how the tables looks)

Comment: @Zarko Personally, I also prefer tables without borders. That's the reason I made all the tables without borders in the first place. But this is my thesis document and I'm in a position where I have to add borders to all the tables.

Comment: With a regex search and replace feature (available in many text editors) you can probably do this fast: replace `\begin{tabular}{` until the next `}` with `\begin{tabular}{|` and `|}`, replace `\end{tabular}` with `\hline\end{tabular}`, etc.. (or adjust accordingly for `booktabs`, `longtable`, ...)